# Finding vector source features in extent with wrapX

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I currently have features on an ol.source.Vector that I would like to find by drawing a box (MultiPolygon) on the screen. I currently have this functionality working, however, if I move onto the next rendered world ("spin the globe" so to speak) when I draw my box over the same set of rendered features I get nothing back.

Example code:

```
var featureSource = new ol.source.Vector({
   url: '/ShinyService/feature/geoJson',
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});
var featureLayer = new ol.layer.Vector( {
   source: featureSource
});

var myMap = new ol.Map({
    layers: [ featureLayer],
    view: new ol.View({
        minZoom: 3,
        maxZoom: 10
    });
});

//Later within interaction event (draw end)
var boxExtent = box.getGeometry().getExtent();
vectorSource.forEachFeatureInExtent(boxExtent, function(feature){
    foundFeature.push(feature.getId());
});
```

I'm currently thinking the only "solution" to this is to no longer allow the world to be rendered multiple times, but I don't think this is an option for the requirement I'm trying to fulfill.

I'm currently using Openlayers v3.18.2

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can u Post the code in plunker?

Comment: I won't be able to post any code for a while (don't have it with me) but I can do my best to answer questions about issues in the meantime

Comment: What if you rerendered (or just translated) the geometry when you passed over? I say this assuming that your box gets drawn somewhere. What is a shinyservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure my problem out. It turned out I had to "wrap" the coordinates of my extent in order to get it to work properly as they were going past the -180 to 180 boundary. Once I did this every thing seemed to work.

However, this feels like something that should already be done in Openlayers so there could be something else I could be missing.

Comment: Can you please let me know how you wrap the extent with a code sample